# Filezilla stop connecting after MLSD

Tags: windows, ftp, filezilla

I have problem in filezilla connecting to the server through FTP client called FTP.

When i try to connect to server i am getting following

```
Status: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 ProFTPD 1.3.4a Server (ProFTPD) [xxx.xxx.xxx.xx]
Command:    USER username
Response:   331 Password required for password
Command:    PASS **********
Response:   230 User username logged in
Command:    SYST
Response:   215 UNIX Type: L8
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Features:
Response:    MDTM
Response:    MFMT
Response:    TVFS
Response:    UTF8
Response:    MFF modify;UNIX.group;UNIX.mode;
Response:    MLST modify*;perm*;size*;type*;unique*;UNIX.group*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.owner*;
Response:    LANG ko-KR;it-IT;ja-JP;ru-RU;bg-BG;zh-CN;fr-FR;zh-TW;en-US*
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:    SIZE
Response:   211 End
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 UTF8 set to on
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (xxx,xxx,xxx,xx,xxx,xxx).
Command:    MLSD
```

And it stop after MLSD and after some time says

```
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I am able to connect to  server through ftp when i connect internet from my mobile.but i dont want to do like that.i need to work with my cable net.

I am using Windows 7 and Laptop.

Please help me to connect.

Answer (score 3):

Because some routers or firewall software blocked MLSD communication for some servers, so my final solution is to stop using FileZilla. Sad.

WinSCP is working fine for me now.

Comment: You saved my day! WinSCP has just handled everything

Answer (score 3):

When a ftp client connects to the ftp server, in most cases passive mode is used.
Then after the client has connected, the server will tell the client which second ftp port to use for the data channel.

But what has this do to with the described issue? Well, quite a lot when the client chooses to use encryption via SSL or better TLS...

Without encryption, most firewalls (on the ftp server side) are able to read the passive-port-communication and then dynamically open the second port within the server's passive port range. This is fine for both sides.

But with encryption the firewalls cannot read which port to open to let the client's data channel connection establish. For this reason, you won't get a response after the MSLD request or any other communication going through the data channel.

If this issue occurs, I bet that in 99.9% of all cases the server-sided firewalling system blocks the client's data-channel-communication. Only possible solution is to use a more sophisticated protocol like SFTP instead - or if possible, statically opening the whole passive port range on the server-sided firewall(s).

Answer (score 2):

Here are several solutions:

We need to clarify that this issue depends on `router`, `filezilla's config` and even some issues with `ipv6`??

- Go to site management, choose the site with the problem. Choose tab "Transfer Settings" and select "active instead of 'default'.
- Verify port is set to 21

If this does not work, try using a ssh tunnel through other server (if available).

[source](http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11405&start=15)

Answer (score 1):

Disable proxy / vpn if you are using any, and try to connect directly.

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem trying to connect to ubuntu server 16 behind a NAT in VirtualBox, the fix was to use passive mode in filezilla and configure file:/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf

PassivePorts 65532 65534

->Change the range as necessary

MasqueradeAddress [MyHost IPAddress or Router external IP in real NAT]

->127.0.0.1 will throw "ECONNREFUSED" instead of "Connection timed out"

Answer (score 0):

use port number 22 instead of 21.

or u can give

ip like

sftp://10.1.10.10.10

instead or giving simply